# Firebase onAuthStateChanged() triggering before retrieving name from signup form?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a dashboard using vanilla HTML, CSS and JS, with Firebase as my backend. In my `signup.html` page, I have a form that allows users to input their name along with their email address and password. Upon signup, users are redirected to `dashboard.html` with their personalized content. Inside the dashboard, it has a spot where it displays their name.

The problem is it is not **always** getting the name from the form, and if it doesn't get the user's name from the signup form then it just doesn't have their name as I don't have a "add name" function in the dashboard. I suspect this is because of the way I use the `onAuthStateChanged()` inside `signup.html`.

The following is my signup page JS code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        window.location.replace('dashboard.html')
    } else {
        return
    }
});

document.querySelector('#signup_btn').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var user_email = document.getElementById('user_email').value;
    var user_pass = document.getElementById('user_pass').value;
    var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;

    // Sign Up
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_pass)
        // Success
        .then((userCredentials) => {
            userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: user_name
            })
        })
        // Errors
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                alert('The password is too weak.');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
        });
})
```

If it helps, here is the form from my `signup.html` page:

```
<form>
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <!-- <h2>Log into your account using your email address</h2> -->

        <label for="user_name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="user_name">

        <label for="user_email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="user_email">

        <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="Password" id="user_pass">

        <button type="submit" id="signup_btn">Sign Up</button>

        <p>Already have an account? <a href="./index.html">Log In</a></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your `onAuthStateChanged` listener is being triggered before the write to the database has completed. This is the expected behavior for the API, but not what you want here.

Since you *do* want to use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener to navigate on page reload, the best I can think off is to turn off the listener when the user clicks the sign up button:

```
//  store the unsubscribe function in a variable
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        window.location.replace('dashboard.html')
    } else {
        return
    }
});

document.querySelector('#signup_btn').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    unsubscribe(); //  turn off auth state listener

    var user_email = document.getElementById('user_email').value;
    var user_pass = document.getElementById('user_pass').value;
    var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;

    // Sign Up
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_pass)
        // Success
        .then((userCredentials) => {
            return userCredentials.user.updateProfile({ //  add a return
                displayName: user_name
            })
        })
        .then(() => {
            window.location.replace('dashboard.html') //  explicitly navigate here
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged),

> onAuthStateChanged adds an observer for changes to the user's sign-in state.

When the user is logged in, it redirects your user to `/dashboard` before the updateProfile is resolved resulting in termination of that request.

[image]

I don't think you'll need an auth state listener on login page so try refactoring the code like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser) window.location.replace("dashboard.html")

  // Else stay on this page
  // button click events here
}
```