# How to sign out user in firebase after creating user with email?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, email-verification

In my app I want to signout the user after creating user with email inorder to verfiy his email. I tried different methods but they aren't working. Here is my code:

```
try {
          await app
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
            .then((userCredential)=>{
              // send verification mail.
              userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
              alert("Email sent");
            })
            .catch(alert);
            //history.push("/");
        } catch (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
```

I have imported firebase initalizer from another component:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});

export default app;
```

Here is my authcontext:

```
useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setPending(false);
    });
  }, []);

  if (pending) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [`signOut`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps) method to log the user out:

```
// unsubscribe Auth listener here
return app.auth()
         .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
         .then(async (userCredential)=>{
           // send verification mail.
           await userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
           await app.auth().signOut();
           alert("Email sent");
         })
```

Although you don't need to log the user out if their email is not verified (depends on how you want your app to work but just a note).
You can simply check if the email is verified, if not then prompt the user to verify it else do not allow them to use the app.

The [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object has a property emailVerified to do so:

```
if (!app.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
  alert("Please verify the email")
}
```

You can also check if the email is verified in security rules:

```
match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified;
}
```

Comment: I tried your first solution before but it isn't working.

Comment: @axfg please try updated answer. I had missed the promises. Please add the async and await as mentioned.

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much. But it is showing the private route for a second before kicking the user out. How to overcome that?

Comment: @axfg please share your code that deals with changing routes. I doubt you have a onAuthStateChanged listener by chance? If the original question is resolved, feel free to accept the answer :) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I use authcontext ,inside it I have onauthstatechanged. How to deal with it?

Comment: @axfg I can't really check what is going on. Can you please share your complete code and explain what's not working? [Gist](https://gist.github.com) might help

Comment: I've edited the question and added the authcontext. Check it.

Comment: @axfg so whenever the auth state changes (users logs in or signs out), that function is triggered and because of that `setCurrentUser()` and `setPending()` are being invoked too. In this case they ideally shoudn't. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68175518/13130697) answer on how to unsubscribe from them.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @axfg the `onAuthStateChanged` will run whenever a user logs in (in your case, a new user account is created) and that is causing `setCurrentUser` function to run. You haven't posted the code for that function but I am assuming that function redirects user to a secured route?

Comment: yes. I know it's triggering the setCurrentUser. What is the workaround for this? or is your second solution more appropriate for this?

Comment: @axfg check the answer that I had shared above. There's another answer from @ Frank which explains how to unsubscribe from the listener

Comment: Ok thank you. What about using emailverified method?

Comment: @axfg I've added a comment in my answer, unsubscribe from the listener there and then keep the rest of the code same

Comment: Sorry to be so naive. What is meant by unsubscribe?

Comment: @axfg by unsubscribe I mean stopping that 'auth state changed' listener. Essentially the code inside of that won't run on any events. (Just like you won't get any notifications from youtube when someone posts a video but you've unsubscribed from the channel)

Comment: I have added a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68191153/16334669). You can also add your answer there.